# Interconnecting two locations with CISCO ASA 5505, providing VPN access as well as and public access

Tags: vpn, certificate, vlan, cisco-asa, network-design

We have two geographically distant networks locations and are thinking about introducing a new network architecture utilizing two [CISCO ASA 5505s](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/prod_models_comparison.html#~mid-range). I'm looking for a review and confirmation whether this architecture is achievable with these two CISCO ASA 5505 Firewalls. I want to be sure this equipment matches our requirements before we make the purchase.

**The network should look like this:**

```
Location 1                                      public servers (on vmware ESXi 4.x)
==========                                      |     (VLAN 1 — DMZ)
Public access  ----> +----------------+ --------+
Mobile worker  ----> | CISCO ASA 5505 |
Internet       <---- +----------------+ --------+
                       ^                        |
                       |                        private servers (on vmware ESXi 4.x)
                       |                              (VLAN 2)
                       | IPsec tunnel (VLAN 2)
                       |
Location 2             |
==========             v
                     +----------------+
Internet       <---- | CISCO ASA 5505 | --------+ 
                     +----------------+         |
                                                LAN workstations and servers
                                                      (VLAN 2)
```

In *Location 1* we have a bunch of virtualized servers running on a couple of physical machines with vmware ESXi 4.x. Several VMs are accessible from the internet by the public and hence need to be placed in a DMZ. Also, our employees that need remote access shall be able to connect with the CISCO VPN client to Location 1's ASA. The required authentication method is with our Windows-based CA's issued user certificates.

The bundle for Location 1 will be ASA5505-UL-BUN-K9.

In *Location 2* we have just workstations and some local servers. However, mobile workers that access Location 1 via VPN need to gain access to machines running in Location 2, so routing from Loc. 1 to Loc. 2 must be configured. VPN access directly to Location 2 is not required, but is nice to have in the future.

The bundle for location 2 will be ASA5505-50-BUN-K9.

Both locations shall be connected by a secure transparent tunnel (e.g. IPsec, AES encryption, pre-shared key most likely).

**Particular questions:**

1. There is a limit on the number of licensed VPN connections. By default, ASA 5505 has 2 SSL VPNs and 10 “remote access” VPNs. Which of these two limits applies when the CISCO VPN client is used? Note that 10 is enough for us, however 2 isn't.
2. VPN connection limit is floating (=currently used) or named (per-assigned-user)?
3. Is it really possible to utilize certificate-based authentication for VPN connection and will it work with a Windows-based Certification Authority?
4. Are there any viable, more cost-effective alternatives to ASA 5505 for Location 2, providing same security, similar routing capabilities? Integrated WiFi access point is a plus.

**Environment:**

- Most servers run Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.
- Workstations run Windows 7 x64.
- There's a single Windows domain.
- vmware server 4 or vmware ESXi 4 for virtualization.
- IPv4

---

Any other hints or recommendations are appreciated. If you find it appropriate, recommend any network equipment from alternative vendors as well.

*I'm not a networking expert and haven't worked with CISCO's equipment for a while, so please ask for any clarifications as needed.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is a limit on the number of
>   licensed VPN connections. By default,
>   ASA 5505 has 2 SSL VPNs and 10 “remote
>   access” VPNs. Which of these two
>   limits applies when the CISCO VPN
>   client is used? Note that 10 is enough
>   for us, however 2 isn't.

**The standard Cisco VPN client is IPSEC, and uses a "remote access" VPN license. The SSL VPN is a clientless VPN and not worth much, unless you purchase the AnyConnect SSL VPN licenses**

> VPN connection limit is floating
>   (=currently used) or named
>   (per-assigned-user)?

**VPN licenses are per VPN peer, and for a mobile access setup it's "concurrent connections."**

> Is it really
>   possible to utilize certificate-based
>   authentication for VPN connection and
>   will it work with a Windows-based
>   Certification Authority?

<strike>**I don't know the answer to this for sure, but my gut feeling is "yes."**</strike>

**Yes, [Microsoft CA supported](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a0080930f21.shtml#req).**

> Are there any viable, more
>   cost-effective alternatives to ASA
>   5505 for Location 2, providing same
>   security, similar routing
>   capabilities? Integrated WiFi access
>   point is a plus.

**I connect Cisco ASAs to various other firewalls via Site to Site IPSEC VPNs quite frequently, so anything that supports the IPSEC VPN standard would be an alternative for site 2.**

Comment: Jake, thanks for the answers so far. My biggest remaining concern is about practical use of certificate-based authentication for VPNs. We were recommended the network configuration described in my question but without any in-depth technical info.

Comment: I'd have to brush up, but I thought certificates were used in the place of pre-shared keys, meaning they are for the IKE negotiation which allows asymmetric encryption and re-negotiation of that encryption on the fly. Your users still provide a username and password to connect.

Comment: Ahh, yes... Certs can be used for authentication. My head was stuck in the SSL VPN context. Updating my answer with link to use a Microsoft CA...

Comment: Might want to post a separate question regarding the merits of certificate authentication vs. RADIUS (password) + pre-shared-key authentication for remote access.

Comment: Guys thanks for clarifying the last issue. I already purchased two boxes and going to test it in a lab.